# Why does the naive definition of fourier transform on $L^2$ fail?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Textbooks always take some care when defining the fourier transform on $L^2$. This suggests that the naive definition fails, i.e. that there is some square-integrable $f$ for which

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\exp(i\omega x)dx$$

does not converge for almost every $\omega$. What is an example of such an $f$?

Comment: As an example $f(x) = \frac1{1+|x|}$, or any other function that is in $L^2$ but not in $L^1$.

Comment: @s.harp Thanks! But I think this wasn't quite the question I meant to ask. I had a second attempt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566399/can-the-fourier-transform-be-defined-on-l2-by-an-improper-integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if we choose $f(x):=x^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty )}(x)$ then
$$
\int_{\Bbb R }|f(x)e^{-i\omega x}|\,\mathrm d x=\int_{[1,\infty )}\frac1{x}\,\mathrm d x=\infty 
$$
so $f\notin L^1(\Bbb R )$ and the Fourier transform can not be defined in the obvious way. However
$$
\int_{\Bbb R }|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm d x=\int_{[1,\infty )}\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm d x=1
$$
so $f\in L^2(\Bbb R )$. Indeed we have that $L^2(\Bbb R )\not\subset L^1(\Bbb R )$ so $f(x)e^{-i\omega x}$ is not integrable in general for any chosen $L^2$ function.

Comment: Thanks! But I think this wasn't quite the question I meant to ask. I had a second attempt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566399/can-the-fourier-transform-be-defined-on-l2-by-an-improper-integral).