# Why can't the Fourier transform be defined on $L^2$ by an improper integral?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

The Fourier transform can be defined on $L^2$ by

$$ \tilde f = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\omega\mapsto\int_{-n}^n f(x)\exp(i\omega x)dx\right),\tag1$$

where the limit is taken in $L^2$. But textbooks always take care to point out that this is the limit of the functions, rather than the 'function of the limits':

$$\omega\mapsto\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^n f(x)\exp(i\omega x)dx.\tag2$$

What would go wrong if you were to use $(2)$ as the definition? Is there some $f$ for which $(2)$ doesn't converge everywhere, or converges to the wrong thing on a set of positive measure?

Comment: This was the question I was trying to ask [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563212/why-does-the-naive-definition-of-fourier-transform-on-l2-fail), but I'd forgotten that the Lebesgue integral on $[-\infty,\infty]$ isn't defined as a limit.

Comment: Consider your favorite function with $x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon}$ decay at infinity.

Comment: I don't know what " the limit of the functions, rather than the 'function of the limits'" means. In any case, since the integral does tend to the FT  in $L^2$ nothing would go wrong if we took it as the defiinition. Btw Carleson's theorem, something like the deepest theorem in Fourier analysis, says that if $f\in L^2$ then that integral does converge to the FT for almost every $\omega$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't see what you're getting at. If my favourite such function is $f(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon}$ for $x\geq1$ and $0$ otherwise, then $(2)$ is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^n x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon}\exp(i\omega x)dx$, which converges by the Dirichlet Test.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Another way to say it would be to ask whether the sequence of functions $\int_{-n}^n f(x)\exp(i\omega x)dx$ always converges pointwise almost everywhere to $\tilde f$ as $n\to\infty$. I think Carleson's theorem answer's my question, so you should add that as an answer if you want.

Comment: I dont see a difference between $\mathrm{(1)}$ and $\mathrm{(2)}$. Indeed in some books the Fourier transform for some $f$ in $L^2$ is defined as the map that you wrote in $\mathrm{(2)}$, by example in *Analysis III* of Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher

Comment: @OscarCunningham In fact Carleson's Theorem says exactly that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere. Whether or not you think it's so, that's what the theorem says.

Comment: @Masacroso The difference is convergence in $L^2$ vs convergence pointwise almost everywhere. I don't see that Amann and Escher do use $(2)$ as their definition. They define the fourier transform for $L^2$ via Theorem 9.23 and Proposition 9.24, and they use convergence in $L^2$ to do so.

Comment: @Oscar as others had pointed the Fourier transform in $L^2$ converges pointwise almost everywhere, so at the end of $\mathrm{(2)}$ you can just write "almost everywhere"

Comment: @OscarCunningham Not quite. The integral on $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't exist in the Lebesgue sense. The Lebesgue integral is typically how the Fourier transform is understood. The perhaps most natural domain of definition for the Fourier transform is $L^1\cap L^2$ which has the richest theory.

Comment: @CameronWilliams No, quite. If $g_n=\int_{-n}^n$ then the integral defining $g_n$ does converge as a Labasgue integral, and in turns out that $g_n\to\hat f$ in $L^2$ and almost everywhere.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah yeah that's a fair way to look at it. I thought the pointwise integral was meant which is bad news here. I despise improper integral notation with Lebesgue integrals.